# nth-child(), including illegal children (malformed HTML)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I'm working with HTML similar to this (coming from a third party web site - this is how the code is served, and I have no control over it):

```
<ul class"list">
    <li>first list item</li>
    <li>second list item</li>
    <div>
        <li>third list item</li>
        <li>fourth list item</li>
    </div>
    <li>fifth list item</li>
    <li>sixth list item</li>
</ul>
```

How can I select the fifth list item using CSS?  With Javascript, if I use `document.querySelectorAll('ul li')` in the DOM, I get an iterable NodeList with all 6 of the `<li>` elements.

So then `let list_items = document.querySelectorAll('ul li')` allows me to access the fifth list item using `list_items[4]`.  But if I try `document.querySelectorAll('ul li:nth-child(5)')` it doesn't work because, apparently, CSS only sees 4 `<li>` elements (the direct children of `<ul>`).

Is there a way to do this with CSS, or do I need to rework my approach?

*** Edit ***

I need to be able to select any of the `li` elements, arbitrarily, based on user input.  The presence and number of `li` elements after the `div` section varies.  I can correctly select any of the `li` elements before the `div` using something like `ul > li:nth-of-type(${index_from_user_input})` - or within the `div` using something like `ul > div > li:nth-of-type(${index_from_user_input})`.  I'm initially counting the number of `li`s and using that as the basis for the indexing...so if user input indicates that I need to select the third `li`, for example, I want to be able to simply use something like `ul li:nth-of-type(3)`.

But if `index_from _user_input` points to an element after the `div`, then it doesn't work correctly, since CSS doesn't recognized the `li`s within the `div`, so the index numbers are off in my selector.  I was hoping for a cleaner solution that uses only `ul li:nth-child()` or `ul li:nth-of-type()` so that I wouldn't have to check how many `li`s are within and after the `div`.  I suspect it's just not possible, given the bad markup, but I'm not 100% sure of that, so I figured I'd ask here, in case somebody might have a clever way to do it.  Otherwise, I can just rework the code and approach the whole thing differently.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: I reworked my approach and solved the problem differently.

Answer (score 0):

> this is how the code is served, and I have no control over it

Oh, you really do. You can just remove the erroneous div from the list with javascript.

**Working Example:**

```js
/* IDENTIFY ELEMENTS */
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var erroneousDiv = list.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

/* IDENTIFY LIST ITEMS */
var allListItems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
var listItemsToMove = erroneousDiv.getElementsByTagName('li');
var numberOfListItemsToMove = listItemsToMove.length;

/* REARRANGE LIST ITEMS AND REMOVE ERRONEOUS DIV */
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfListItemsToMove; i++) {
    list.insertBefore(listItemsToMove[0], erroneousDiv);
}

list.removeChild(erroneousDiv);


/* SELECTOR FUNCTION */
function selectListItem() {
    for (var i = 0; i < allListItems.length; i++) {
        allListItems[i].removeAttribute('style');
    }

    var selected = select.value;
    var listItem = document.querySelector('ul li:nth-of-type(' + selected + ')');
    listItem.style.color = 'blue';
    listItem.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}

button.addEventListener('click', selectListItem, false);
```

```css
ul, form {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 80px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class"list">
    <li>first list item</li>
    <li>second list item</li>
    <div>
        <li>third list item</li>
        <li>fourth list item</li>
    </div>
    <li>fifth list item</li>
    <li>sixth list item</li>
</ul>

<form>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>

</select>
<button type="button">Select List Item</button>
</form>
```